# How to make C# 2017 IntelliSense work like 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

In Visual C# 2008 Express, the IntelliSense is great, e.g. I only have to type `Conso.(` and it will insert `Console.Write(`

That works as follows:
(i) `Conso` is enough disambiguation to select `Console` in the list; (ii) typing `.` automatically inserts that highlighted word and adds the dot too; (iii) now the dropdown list shows `Console`'s members, defaulting to `Write` [based on my usage frequency?], (iv) now typing `(` automatically inserts that highlighted word and adds the bracket too.

**Note that I did not need to type any of the letters of `Write`, nor all of `Console`, nor did I have to press Space, Tab, Enter etc. to confirm anything.**

I have now upgraded to VS 2017 and the autocomplete works differently. You have to press special keys (Tab, Enter etc.) to insert the word from the list. It won't insert the highlighted item for you automatically as soon as you move on to the next punctuation.

Having to select all these list items manually is murdering my productivity. I can see some autocomplete options in the Tools>Options but I find nothing that can achieve what I had in C# 2008. Is it still possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this issue was removed from the VS 2017 and VS 2015, I tried to help you report this user voice to the VS Product Team, please check this: [C#>Intellisense: please auto pre-select the common used members like the previous VS version](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/452755/cintellisense-please-auto-pre-select-the-common-us.html) and you can also add a comment in there to trace the feedback from the VS Product Team engineers.

Comment: It's strange, but since I posted here, the problem seems to have "fixed itself". I haven't changed any settings. All I can think is that maybe it depends on what you have opened (e.g. a whole solution versus a single source file), or something like that...